# Java exec adb commands But not output

Tags: java, exec, adb

Environment :Ubuntu jdk1.8 eclipse

```
String []cmdHeader={"/bin/bash","-c","adb"};
Runtime cmd=Runtime.getRuntime();;
    Process p=cmd.exec(cmdHeaher);;
    BufferedReader br=
                    new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line=br.readLine();
            while(line!=null){
                System.out.println(1);
                System.out.println(line);
                line=br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
```

There are some details I omitted.

In this cmd,the console shows nothing.Why?

ps:
adb is ok when I run it on bash window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your command line, execute `which adb`. This will give you the full path to the `adb` command, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/adb`.

Then in your code replace `adb` with the full path you got from the command line, for example:

```
String[] cmdHeader = {"/bin/bash","-c","/usr/local/bin/adb"};
```

Comment: It worked,but the path I writed is the install path of adt./opt/adt/platforms-tools/adb.Does it means that the user should set the path manualy?But I have set the pathfile of ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you.However -l doesn't work.And I decide to let user set it manualy.Thanks again.

Comment: It all depends on where you configured the path. For example, on my Ubuntu installation, my `/$HOME/.bash_profile` does get sourced by running with `-l`.